# Openfaas call one function from another in Multi-stage

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, openfaas

I have followed these two documents  [openfaas workshop](https://github.com/openfaas/workshop/blob/f27ff19c87b0933c51799586d83d5e75cbd78eb2/lab4.md#call-one-function-from-another) ,[multi-stage](https://www.openfaas.com/blog/gke-multi-stage/) implementing **openfaas** functions on Kubernetes.

Part of [multi-stage](https://www.openfaas.com/blog/gke-multi-stage/) article says:

> Note that the above configuration will prohibit functions from calling each other or from reaching the OpenFaaS core services.

There is role binding configuration on ingress which avoid function to call each other.

What is the solution to that can able function to call each other but secure?

Comment: The [multi-stage blog post](https://www.openfaas.com/blog/gke-multi-stage/) you're referring to talks about preventing the core services (like API gateway or NATS message router) to be accessed from the functions you deploy. You should be able to call them through their DNS name, though (like http://gateway:8080/ or http://gateway.the.dns.name:8080/)